# Fallo específico con Calculadora en Swift

Tags: swift

Estoy programando una calculadora en Swift con poca experiencia y practica programando con lo cual supongo que estaré siguiendo una logica rudimentaria. Aun así me gustaría saber como corregir el siguiente fallo:

Todas las operaciones se realizan correctamente salvo las que se hacen despues de darle al signo = ( el = realiza correctamente la operacion que debe, pero a partir de ahi si quieres realizar otra, la hace mal).

**La logica de las operaciones es la siguiente:**

- variable numA
- variable numB
- numA = numA (operacion segun signo pulsado) numB

Esta es la funcion asociada a los signos operadores ( + *  / ):

```
 @IBAction func operar(sender: UIButton) {

    operador = sender.currentTitle!
    print(operador)



    if ( numA == 0 ) {

        let operando = Int(guardaResultado)
        numA = operando!

        resultado.text = ""

        print("numA es \(numA)")
        print("numB es \(numB)")



    }

    else {


        let operando = Int(guardaResultado)



        if ( operador == "+") {


            numB = operando!
            resultado.text = "+"
            numA = numA + numB
            operador = "+"
            print(operador)
        }
        else if ( operador == "/") {




            numB = operando!
            resultado.text = ""
            numA = numA / numB



        }
        else if ( operador == "*") {

            numB = operando!
            resultado.text = ""
            numA = numA * numB
        }



        print("numA es \(numA)")
        print("numB es \(numB)")


    }


}
```

**Y Esta funcióon es la asociada con el signo =**

```
@IBAction func mostrarResultado(sender: AnyObject) {

    var operando = Int(guardaResultado)


    if ( operador == "+") {

        numB = operando!
        numA = numA + numB



        resultado.text = String(numA)


    }
    else if ( operador == "/") {




        numB = operando!
        numA = numA / numB
        resultado.text = String(numA)



    }
    else if ( operador == "*") {

        numB = operando!
        numA = numA * numB
        resultado.text = String(numA)
    }

    //numA = 0
    //numB = 0


    operador = ""


    print("numA es \(numA)")
    print("numB es \(numB)")
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Quizas ayude el proporcinar un ejemplo escrito de los errores que estas experimentado despues de aplicar "=". Por ejemplo cuando hago 3+2=5, bien pero depues hago "lo que usted haga y el error que obtiene". Creo que seria mas facil para entender su error. Saludos

Comment: ¿Como conoce tu función mostrarResultado los valores de numA y/o numB cuando estos no son el operando?  ¿Operador y operando son convertidos a int antes de operar con ellos? No veo ni una cosa ni otra.

Comment: imagino que lo que quieres hacer es que si haces 3+4 al darle = te diga 7, pero que si después le das +2 te salga 9, es así? tienes que aplicar mas programación a eso. Deberas, una vez que le des al = guardar el resultado. Si después le dan a un operador y no tienes numA, deberas poner el que tenias guardado, es para que sigas probando, pero tiene mas cosas de las que piensas. Un buen ejercicio para ir practicando

Comment: Quizás lo mejor sería una variable sólo para mostrar el resultado, la cual se limpia cada vez que vas a realizar una nueva operación. Lo mismo se está quedando guardado el valor de la operación anterior. De todas formas estaría bien un ejemplo de la operación que realizas y el resultado que te da para ver exactamente qué te está pasando.